# Recommended OS and kernel upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lts

We have a few servers running on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64. I would like to know what is the recommended OS and kernel upgrade for that particular version. And how can I do it without internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know what is the recommended OS and kernel upgrade for that particular version.

The next LTS after that would be 14.04 LTS.

> And how can I do it without internet connection?

You will need an internet connection of some sorts. Ubuntu is an operating system depending highly on an internet connection being present. Your best method would be to connect the system to the internet and upgrade through that.

If the server is important to be up and running asap all other methods will be risky and will consume a lot of time.

There is a tool called "apt-offline" where you use an internet connection from a remote system to download packages. It can be used to upgrade BUT the list it generates is based on the system the command it run so you will need another system that is similar and does have an internet connection. So that defeats the purpose: if that is a workable method you could just attach that server you want upgraded to the web.

---

We tend to NOT upgrade. At our office we have more than 1 server and we rotate them: 14.04 is on an active server, 12.04 is on the older server and this will get the 16.04 when it arrives (and will become the active server again).

That way we can tinker all we want and only have a few minutes downtime when the router is changed.

---

Alternative

- burn a 14.04 dvd
- backup all your data (apache, mysql settings are pretty easy to make backups from and you probably already have a backup tool running).
- install 14.04
- install the software you use.
- restore your data.

Comment: Why do you recommend upgrading to 14.04? I see no reason for a server, if it works.

Comment: @Pilot6: because that's what the OP asked?  They want to upgrade to the next LTS version instead of waiting until support runs out...  **;-)**

Comment: @Pilot6 I interpreted this "the recommended OS and kernel upgrade for that particular version"  as a possible upgrade to the next LTS version. The upgrade path is available from 12.04 to 14.04 plus it will include a newer kernel. 14.04 has some tweaks compared to 12.04 (plus new apache and mysql).